# Filename is interpreted differently on Web Server than on Localhost

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I've built a Website that uses a MySQL database and it works correctly on my Localhost using xamp. But, when I copy the exact files(including the Database) using Filezilla on the Web Server, the files that are named with an accent, in my case the file named `Caffè.jpg` can't be found for some reason.

Basically, the database contains the name of the files so if I have a record called `Juices` inside the database, then PHP is going to build the website and it's going to take the file named `Juices.jpg` from the storage. Even on the Web Server, all the other files work great, but only the words with an accent are not working correctly. I get this error on the Web Server:

`GET http://www.website.com/STRUCTURE/IMAGES/Caff%EF%BF%BD.jpg 404 (Not Found)`

I know that the error might come from the fact that the Database on the Web Server uses a different encoding than on Localhost but I don't think that's the cause. Take a look at this image:
[image]

To get the images on the page, I wrote this line: `<img src=\"./STRUCTURE/IMAGES/".$datas[$i]['name'].".jpg\" class=\"card_image\">`

As you can see I made sure to use the same encoding on both Databases and in the `index.php` file I even added the line `<meta charset="utf-8"/>`. I tried all the solution I could think of and found online but with no result. In case it might be useful, I use `Aruba.it` for my Web Server. In case you need more details I can easily modify the post. Thank You in advance!

Comment: See "black diamond" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your MySQL server has utf8mb4 connection

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character%';
```

Edit MySQL config (/etc/my.cnf) something like this

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8mb4
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4;'
collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

Restart MySQL server

```
service mysqld restart
```

Comment: Thank you. So, I tried the first two queries and the result is: ```collation_connection->utf8mb4_general_ci
collation_database->utf8mb4_general_ci
collation_server->latin1_swedish_ci``` and it still doesn't work. I have to say that I don't have access to the my.cnf file for now, only to the GUI of the Database and also the server collation is in latin_swedish, I don't know what to do.

Comment: Do you have root access in phpMyAdmin? Which results for second query? SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character%';